# Convert Jmeter __V function variable into groovy vars.get

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a JMeter variable like this:

```
${__V(myVar${counter})}
```

How to get the value of this variable inside JSR223 sampler by using **vars.get()** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested get:

```
 vars.get("myVar" + vars.get("counter" ));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Use "Parameters" section of the JSR223 Sampler (as the [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) suggests)

   [image]
2. Use [GString Template feature](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_gstringtemplateengine) like:

   ```
   vars.get("myVar${counter}")
   ```

   where `vars` is the shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see the JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article to learn more about JMeter API shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements